# WCF JSON data not showing in browser

Tags: c#, json, wcf

Was trying alot and brows-ing around but I fail to figure out what is wrong with my WCF service.

**What I am trying to acchive:**
I am builindg a WCF that would expose some data as a json structure over HTTP

I will evenutally use that in an andorid app to show the data.

**The mockup:**

1.) The interface:

```
namespace WcfSyncDBService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ISyncDBService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISyncDBService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetTodoItems")]
        TodoItem[] GetTodoItems();
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "TodoItems")]
    public class TodoItem
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set;}
        [DataMember(Name = "Category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Summary")]
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2.) The Service:

```
namespace WcfSyncDBService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "SyncDBService" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class SyncDBService : ISyncDBService
    {

        public TodoItem[] GetTodoItems()
        {
            var context = new SyncDBEntities();
            var query = from i in context.todo select i;
            var itemList = query.ToList();

            List<TodoItem> todoList = new List<TodoItem>();

            foreach (var item in itemList)
            {
                TodoItem i = new TodoItem
                                 {
                                     Id =  item.C_id,
                                     Category = item.category,
                                     Summary = item.summary,
                                     Description = item.description
                                 };
                todoList.Add(i);
            }
            return todoList.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

3.) Web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfSyncDBService.SyncDBService">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfSyncDBService.ISyncDBService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SyncDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SyncDBmodel.csdl|res://*/SyncDBmodel.ssdl|res://*/SyncDBmodel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=SyncDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

When I run the service I get the definition and the wsdl:

```
http://localhost:18131/SyncDBService.svc
```

But when I try to call the function `http://localhost:18131/SyncDBService.svc/GetTodoItems/` I get an error **"Endpoint not found."**

I know the error is probably in the web.config but I simply fail to find it hope someone can help me out.

EDIT1: (web.config after Siva's sugesstion)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfSyncDBService.SyncDBService">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfSyncDBService.ISyncDBService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        <serviceActivations>
            <add relativeAddress="SyncDBService.svc" service="WcfSyncDBService.SyncDBService" />
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SyncDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SyncDBmodel.csdl|res://*/SyncDBmodel.ssdl|res://*/SyncDBmodel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=SyncDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: sorry that was me being newbish I called http://localhost:18131/SyncDBService.svc/GetTodoItems/ instead of http://localhost:18131/SyncDBService.svc/GetTodoItems

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure relative address on service host,

```
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        <serviceActivations>
            <add relativeAddress="SyncDBService.svc" service="WcfSyncDBService.SyncDBService" />
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion but still the same problem I added the code you sugested above